# how to convert "Tue, 14 Jul 2015 15:00:00 +0000" in iOS 8.1

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I've tried convert the string to `NSDate` by this way:

```
NSString *str = @"Tue, 14 Jul 2015 15:00:00 +0000";

NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzzz"];

NSDate* aDate = [formatter dateFromString:str];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:aDate]);
```

but it is null, what is the real way?

Comment: i'm sorry , nsdate not nsdata

Comment: `hh` won't work for 24-hour time. And `zzzz` is wrong for the timezone. Double check the spec for date formatters.

Comment: you can always edit your question. Also, for best results please read the following article before posting questions. Doing so increases your chances of getting a good answer to your questions.http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you need to spot the difference between `hh` and `HH`; while the `hh` can parse hours in range of __0-11__, the `HH` can parse hours in range of __0-23__. that is why your first attempt fails, the `hh` cannot parse the number 15, so the parsing procedure gracefully falls back to a simple `nil`.

Comment: tks for your comments, this is the first time i use S.O., so made some mistakes.Should I do anything to close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this and it should work the result is :

```
Jul 14,2015 16:00:00 (based on my time zone)
```

Here is the code:

```
NSString *str = @"Tue, 14 Jul 2015 15:00:00 +0000";

NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];


[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];

NSDate* aDate = [formatter dateFromString:str];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
//formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]; if you want to avoid converting the time to the current timezone

NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:aDate]);
```

[Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: The OP doesn't want the timezone in the 2nd format. And why are you forcing GMT in the 2nd format? The OP wants local time based on their original code.

Comment: @rmaddy i have edited the answer taking consideration your suggestions

Comment: tks,that's what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you -

```
NSString *str = @"Tue, 14 Jul 2015 15:00:00 +0000";
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
NSDate* aDate = [formatter dateFromString:str];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:aDate]);
```